# Sklearn inverse_transformation does not work as expected, any alternatives?

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn, lstm, data-preprocessing

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

values = df[['Close']] #values is floats ranging from 0.06 to 190.08

sc = MinMaxScaler()
scaled_values = sc.fit_transform(values)
descaled_values = sc.inverse_transform(scaled_values)
```

My problem is descaled values and original values does not match here. And since i cannot use inverse_transform, i can't convert my predicted value to an unscaled value.

I wrote the inversing function manually to understand:

```
def descale_prediction(predicted_value):

    return predicted_value * (maximum_value - minimum_value) + minimum_value
```

And realized that problem isn't the scaler but range of my values. Question is, what can i do alternatively to convert a scaled prediction value to unscaled one?

I'm sorry if this looks terrible, i don't really know how to use this website. :/

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by problem coming from range of your values. Maybe try using `StandardScaler` instead which scales values using units of variance

Comment: I can’t reproduce this. Can you make a complete example with actual test values that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: A common mistake in this situation is to call `sc.fit_transform()` multiple times. When this happens, the scaler only remembers the parameters for doing the last transformation. Is that what's happening here?